# iOS: foursquare request fails

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, foursquare

I am assigned to work with foursquare just recently. I have an app that needs to be authenticated and access the foursquare environment. I am having trouble with the following code to access checkins. I had already successfully made the authentication but the thing is that when I made a check in request, an errorType invalid_auth code 401 appears. I just don't know what's wrong with this.

Here is my full code; I am using fsq wrapper I found in github:

```
#import "FSQViewController.h"

#define kClientID      @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
#define kCallbackURL   @"invitation://foursquare"

@interface FSQViewController()
@property(nonatomic,readwrite,strong) BZFoursquare *foursquare;
@property(nonatomic,strong) BZFoursquareRequest *request;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary *meta;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *notifications;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary *response;
@end


@implementation FSQViewController

@synthesize foursquare = foursquare_;
@synthesize request = request_;
@synthesize meta = meta_;
@synthesize notifications = notifications_;
@synthesize response = response_;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.foursquare = [[BZFoursquare alloc]initWithClientID:kClientID callbackURL:kCallbackURL];
        foursquare_.version = @"20120206";
        foursquare_.locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale]objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
        foursquare_.sessionDelegate = (id<BZFoursquareSessionDelegate>) self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark BZFoursquareRequestDelegate

- (void)requestDidFinishLoading:(BZFoursquareRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"test");
    self.meta = request.meta;
    self.notifications = request.notifications;
    self.response = request.response;
    self.request = nil;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)request:(BZFoursquareRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"HERE > %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"errorDetail"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    self.meta = request.meta;
    self.notifications = request.notifications;
    self.response = request.response;
    self.request = nil;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark BZFoursquareSessionDelegate

- (void)foursquareDidAuthorize:(BZFoursquare *)foursquare {
    NSLog(@"authorized!");
}

- (void)foursquareDidNotAuthorize:(BZFoursquare *)foursquare error:(NSDictionary *)errorInfo {
    NSLog(@"not authorized! %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, errorInfo);
}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {

    if (![foursquare_ isSessionValid]){ 
        NSLog(@"here");
        [foursquare_ startAuthorization];
    } else {
        [foursquare_ invalidateSession];
    }
}

- (IBAction)checkin:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"4d341a00306160fcf0fc6a88", @"venueId", @"public", @"broadcast", kClientID, @"oauth_token", nil];
    self.request = [foursquare_ requestWithPath:@"checkins/add" HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameters:parameters delegate:self];
    [request_ start];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

@end
```

can you help me guys? any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: It looks okay.. can you debug it and give us the fully formatted post request that is done.. the 401 from 4sq means the kClientID is holding an invalid token.

Comment: I placed the client id I got from registering a consumer in foursquare..

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses

401 (Unauthorized)  The OAuth token was provided but was invalid.

Might you have somehow corrupted your oauth token?

Comment: This is likely the case.  He should print out the response message.  I would imagine it says that

Answer (score -1):

I am using the code below & it is working for me :

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"venueId": @"4a0c6465f964a5202a751fe3", @"broadcast": @"public",@"oauth_token":kClientID};
```